# Update the a href after page load

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I am using the [Stacktack app](https://stackapps.com/q/518/14135) to put the summary of post on a website. But, when the stacktack load's the page, the links point to direct url to stackoverflow site, but I want to amend the href link to something else (append a number to it).

**Example** If I give the id of current post, the link that stacktack add to the question is the complete one

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212050/update-the-a-href-after-page-load
```

I want it to be the share link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/13212050/1135954
```

I am using jquery to do this as

```
var ele = $('h3').find('a');
var l =ele.length;
for(var i=0;i<l;i++) {
    var toLink = ele[i].href+"/1135954" ;  /* Not exact change, but point is to update the link */
    console.log(toLink);
    $(ele[i]).attr("href",toLink);
}
```

But this is not updating the links, as the content of the stacktack is not yet loaded. I tried to do a alert on the length.

So, how would I be able to call this piece of code only after the stacktack has finished loading the content?

Please let me know

Comment: are you wrapping it in a jQuery(document).ready() statement?

Comment: What's up with all the fiddling around when you can just do : `ele[i].href = ele[i].href+"/1135954";`

Comment: Yes I am wrapping it up in `.ready()`, but yet it display's 0.

Comment: I think you may be calling data after document ready. Try calling this code from body onload.

Comment: @adeneo your settimeout also work's perfectly. Was about to comment, but seems your post is deleted.

Comment: @mtk - Yes, you accepted an answer, so I stopped fiddling with it. It may well be that using the body onload function works, but it is indeed the wrong answer, as the plugin does an asynchronous ajax request, and when that has completed the content is inserted dynamically. Using a timeout, or for that matter the body onload function, only gives you a little more time for the ajax to complete. Should the ajax for some reason use more time then the body uses to load, and it very well could, changing the anchors will fail miserably.

Comment: hmm.. I get your point. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the possible reason that it is happening is because you're loading the content after the document loads. So try calling this code on body load.

```
<body onload="fun()"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dom must be loaded before you use any selectors.
Use [$.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery you could do it simpler just like following:

```
$('h3').find('a').each(function(index, element) {
    currentLink = element.attr('href');
    updatedLink = currentLink+'/1234567'
    $(this).attr('href', updatedLink);
});
```

Comment: The point is the number of element it shows is zero (0), and hence the links are not getting updated. The content's of stacktack are not yet loaded.

Comment: then put the following script above in the `$(document).ready();` function and be sure you put it underneath the js you need to have loaded just to be on the safe side.